# Can't see ARP poisoning packets on Wireshark and Scapy

Tags: wireshark, python, arp-spoofing, arp

I'm trying to create a python script to detect ARP poisoning on WiFi networks. I'm using scapy and wireshark to check scapy's output. I'm stuck trying to see all ARP traffic on the network, I can only see packets sent by me and broadcasted ones. Is this correct or should I see all traffic? My intention is to see a ARP response saying `IP 192.168.1.1 is at attackers_Mac` and based on this, alert about attack.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

You will only be able to see ARP traffic sent to you or broadcast to `FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF`.

If you want to see ARP traffic over the whole network then this depends on the network architecture. Wireshark [shows some ideas](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Ethernet) on how this could be achieved such as MiTM or using a hub.

If capturing WiFi traffic, your wireless adapter could be put into monitor mode where it would then capture all wireless traffic nearby.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But when talking about WiFi network, every packet is sent it through the air and so anyone should be able to capture it. Am i wrong?

Comment: Yep that's right. Use monitor mode and then you can capture all wireless traffic.

Comment: That's the point, if using monitor mode, I can only capture 802.11 packets. Is there any way to decrypt the traffic and analyze ARP packets or just (using mode monitor on WiFi) capture ARP traffic?

Comment: If you use monitor mode you will need to know the WiFi passphrase to decrypt the traffic. Wireshark has a feature built in to do this.

Comment: Do you know any python library or bash script to decrypt it? Thank you.

Comment: I haven't used anything personally, but I've just had a look around and found this [Python wrapper for tshark](https://github.com/KimiNewt/pyshark) which could be of use to decrypt 802.11 traffic.